# Error creating Azure AKS Cluster from Terraform version 1.27.9 - Changing property 'networkProfile.podCIDR' from '10.244.0.0/16' to '' is not allowed

Tags: azure, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

As of today - our terraform AzureRM/AKS (version 7.5.0) install stopped working.

We set the following as we post install Calico CNI:

```
    network_plugin                      = "none" # None as we're installing calico
    net_profile_pod_cidr                = null
    net_profile_service_cidr            = null
    net_profile_dns_service_ip          = null
    net_profile_outbound_type           = "userDefinedRouting"
```

Now the cluster is created, but then post the create we get the following error

```
│ RESPONSE 400: 400 Bad Request
│ ERROR CODE: PropertyChangeNotAllowed
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ {
│   "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
│   "details": null,
│   "message": "Changing property 'networkProfile.podCIDR' from '10.244.0.0/16' to '' is not allowed.",
│   "subcode": "",
│   "target": "networkProfile.podCIDR"
│ }
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ 
│ 
│   with module.workload.module.aks.azapi_update_resource.aks_cluster_post_create,
│   on .terraform/modules/workload.aks/main.tf line 562, in resource "azapi_update_resource" "aks_cluster_post_create":
│  562: resource "azapi_update_resource" "aks_cluster_post_create" {
│
```

Looks like even though we explicitly set the pod_cidr to null, it gets set to the default value "10.244.0.0/16"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/create-or-update?view=rest-aks-2023-11-01&tabs=HTTP#containerservicenetworkprofile

We have tried the following pod_cidr settings which all fail

1. setting to an empty string which is rejected as well.
2. not setting at all
3. setting to "none" string
4. setting to the default value "10.244.0.0/16" - even that fails with the same error.

This worked up to today when our Azure region released new versions of AKS.

Code Example (extract from our project and simplified) which replicates this issue

```
locals {
  cluster_subnet_id                     = "YOURSUBNETID"
  aks_kubernetes_version                = "1.27.9"
  rbac_aad_admin_group_object_ids       = [ "YOUR AAD ADMIN GROUP" ]
  rg_name                               = "YOUR RESOURCE GROUP"
  location                              = "australiaeast"
  aks = {
    agents_availability_zones           = [1,2,3]
    agents_count                        = null # set to null while autoscaling is enabled
    enable_auto_scaling                 = true
    enable_host_encryption              = false # https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-enable-host-based-encryption-cli
    identity_type                       = "SystemAssigned"
    ingress_application_gateway_enabled = false
    key_vault_secrets_provider_enabled  = true
    kms_enabled                         = false
    kms_key_vault_network_access        = "Private"
    log_analytics_workspace_enabled     = false
    network_plugin                      = "none" # None as we're installing calico
    net_profile_pod_cidr                = null
    net_profile_service_cidr            = null
    net_profile_dns_service_ip          = null
    net_profile_outbound_type           = "userDefinedRouting"
    oidc_issuer_enabled                 = true
    os_disk_size_gb                     = 100
    private_cluster_enabled             = true # restricts Kube API access to private networks only.
    private_cluster_public_fqdn_enabled = true
    private_dns_zone_id                 = null
    public_network_access_enabled       = false
    role_based_access_control_enabled   = true
    rbac_aad                            = true
    rbac_aad_managed                    = true
    local_account_disabled              = true
    sku_tier                            = "Free" # Standard once we're over 10 nodes and in prod
    temporary_name_for_rotation         = "tmp"  #must be less than 12 characters - and only lowercase lettersyes
    workload_identity_enabled           = true #Use Azure workload identity (map aad identities to pods)
    azure_policy_enabled                = false
    network_contributor_role_assigned_subnet_ids = {
      cluster_subnet = local.cluster_subnet_id
    }
    node_pools = {
      spots = {
        name                   = "spots"
        vm_size                = "Standard_D2s_v4"
        enable_auto_scaling    = true
        min_count              = 3
        max_count              = 4
        eviction_policy        = "Delete"
        enable_host_encryption = true
        priority               = "Spot"
        spot_max_price         = "0.50"
        zones                  = [1,2,3]
        node_taints            = ["kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority=spot:NoSchedule"]
        vnet_subnet_id         = local.cluster_subnet_id
      }
    }
  }
}

module "aks" {
  source                                       = "Azure/aks/azurerm"
  version                                      = "7.5.0"
  resource_group_name                          = local.rg_name
  location                                     = local.location
  cluster_name                                 = "aks-test-cluster"
  prefix                                       = "aks-test"
  vnet_subnet_id                               = local.cluster_subnet_id
  identity_type                                = local.aks.identity_type
  agents_availability_zones                    = local.aks.agents_availability_zones
  agents_count                                 = local.aks.agents_count
  agents_size                                  = "Standard_D2s_v4"
  agents_min_count                             = 3
  agents_max_count                             = 3
  enable_auto_scaling                          = local.aks.enable_auto_scaling
  enable_host_encryption                       = local.aks.enable_host_encryption
  key_vault_secrets_provider_enabled           = local.aks.key_vault_secrets_provider_enabled
  kms_enabled                                  = local.aks.kms_enabled
  kms_key_vault_network_access                 = local.aks.kms_key_vault_network_access
  kubernetes_version                           = "1.27.9"
  log_analytics_workspace_enabled              = local.aks.log_analytics_workspace_enabled
  network_plugin                               = local.aks.network_plugin
  net_profile_pod_cidr                         = local.aks.net_profile_pod_cidr
  net_profile_service_cidr                     = local.aks.net_profile_service_cidr
  net_profile_dns_service_ip                   = local.aks.net_profile_dns_service_ip
  net_profile_outbound_type                    = local.aks.net_profile_outbound_type
  oidc_issuer_enabled                          = local.aks.oidc_issuer_enabled
  orchestrator_version                         = local.aks_kubernetes_version
  os_disk_size_gb                              = local.aks.os_disk_size_gb
  private_cluster_enabled                      = local.aks.private_cluster_enabled
  private_cluster_public_fqdn_enabled          = local.aks.private_cluster_public_fqdn_enabled
  private_dns_zone_id                          = local.aks.private_dns_zone_id
  # public_network_access_enabled                = local.aks.public_network_access_enabled
  role_based_access_control_enabled            = local.aks.role_based_access_control_enabled
  rbac_aad                                     = local.aks.rbac_aad
  rbac_aad_managed                             = local.aks.rbac_aad_managed
  rbac_aad_admin_group_object_ids              = local.rbac_aad_admin_group_object_ids
  local_account_disabled                       = local.aks.local_account_disabled
  sku_tier                                     = local.aks.sku_tier
  node_pools                                   = local.aks.node_pools
  azure_policy_enabled                         = local.aks.azure_policy_enabled
  workload_identity_enabled                    = local.aks.workload_identity_enabled
  temporary_name_for_rotation                  = local.aks.temporary_name_for_rotation
  attached_acr_id_map = {

  }
}
```

Comment: Help me understand something, If you want to use calico why aren't you using 
`network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku  = "standard"
    network_policy     = "calico"
  }`

Comment: Sorry - good question - we're using the calico cni plugin - not just for policy, as per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-byo-cni?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: @MikeElmsly Try removing the  net_profile_pod_cidr                = null
    net_profile_service_cidr            = null
    net_profile_dns_service_ip          = null 

as they don't provide any info here also please share the code configuration in the query to have a better understanding of the requirement and also the provider info which you included

Comment: @VinayB - we've tried multiple settings for the pod_cidr etc with the same result.  I've updated the description to better describe this.

Comment: in one of those oddities of life - it's working this morning, no code changes.
thanks for attempting to help - I didn't find a solution but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

> Deploying Azure AKS with Calico CNI Using Terraform: A Configuration Guide

Your Terraform AzureRM/AKS setup is causing an error because of a mismatch between the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) API and the `networkProfile.podCIDR` property. Azure does not let you change this property to an empty value or `null` after you create the cluster if it already has a default or a different value. This can create problems when you want to deploy AKS clusters with custom network settings, especially if you use network plugins like Calico that need certain configurations.

The problem seems to be related to changing `networkProfile.podCIDR` after creating the cluster. This might mean that Terraform did not set `podCIDR` to `null` as you intended when it created the AKS cluster, perhaps because of how the Azure API handles these settings. This could also cause network issues that might be resolved by changing the network.

**My Configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  location                          = "East US"
  rg_name                           = "VkProject-test-rg"
  aks = {
    identity_type                   = "SystemAssigned"
    agents_availability_zones       = ["1", "2", "3"]
    agents_count                    = 3
    enable_auto_scaling             = true
    enable_host_encryption          = false
    key_vault_secrets_provider_enabled = true
    kms_enabled                     = false
    kms_key_vault_network_access    = false
    log_analytics_workspace_enabled = true
    network_plugin                  = "none"
    net_profile_service_cidr        = "10.0.0.0/16"
    net_profile_dns_service_ip      = "10.0.0.10"
    net_profile_outbound_type       = "loadBalancer"
    oidc_issuer_enabled             = false
    aks_kubernetes_version          = "1.23.5"
    os_disk_size_gb                 = 50
    private_cluster_enabled         = false
    private_cluster_public_fqdn_enabled = false
    private_dns_zone_id             = "None"
    role_based_access_control_enabled = true
    rbac_aad                        = false
    rbac_aad_managed                = false
    rbac_aad_admin_group_object_ids = []
    local_account_disabled          = false
    sku_tier                        = "Free"
  }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
  name     = local.rg_name
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "vk-logs-workspace"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "aks-test-cluster"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks-test"

  default_node_pool {
    name                = "default"
    node_count          = local.aks.agents_count
    vm_size             = "Standard_DS2_v2"
   // availability_zones  = local.aks.agents_availability_zones
    enable_auto_scaling = local.aks.enable_auto_scaling
    min_count           = 1
    max_count           = 5
  }

  identity {
    type = local.aks.identity_type
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = local.aks.network_plugin
    service_cidr       = local.aks.net_profile_service_cidr
    dns_service_ip     = local.aks.net_profile_dns_service_ip
    outbound_type      = local.aks.net_profile_outbound_type
  }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]